# why won't my background refresh

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

my background wont refresh and it keeps on saying game over.

i am trying to get one sprite on one side to move up and down and fire periodically and have a player sprite only be able move up and down and trys to fire a 'shoot' sprite at the enemy sprite

```
import pygame, random, sys
from pygame.locals import *

WINDOWWIDTH = 600
WINDOWHEIGHT = 600
TEXTCOLOR = (255, 255, 255)
BGC = (0, 0, 0)
FPS = 80
PLAYERMOVERATE = 5
countBy = 10

def terminate():
    pygame.quit()
    sys.exit()

def waitForPlayerToPressKey():
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                terminate()
            if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                    terminate()
                return

def playerHasHitShoot(playerRect, shoot):
    if playerRect.colliderect(shoot):
        return True
    return False

def baddieHasHitShoot(baddieRect, shoot):
    if baddieRect.colliderect(shoot):
        return True
    return False

def drawText(text, font, surface, x, y):
    textobj = font.render(text, 1, TEXTCOLOR)
    textrect = textobj.get_rect()
    textrect.topleft = (x, y)
    surface.blit(textobj, textrect)

pygame.init()
pygame.font.init()
font = pygame.font.SysFont(None,48)
mainClock = pygame.time.Clock()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WINDOWWIDTH, WINDOWHEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption('Mothers Day')
pygame.mouse.set_visible(True)
pygame.display.set_icon(pygame.image.load('gameicon.gif'))

gameStartSound = pygame.mixer.Sound('gamestart.wav')
gameOverSound = pygame.mixer.Sound('gameend.wav')
pygame.mixer.music.load('background.wav')

playerImage = pygame.image.load('starship.bmp')
playerRect = playerImage.get_rect()
baddieImage = pygame.image.load('enemy.bmp')
baddieRect = baddieImage.get_rect()
shootImage = pygame.image.load('shoot.bmp')
shootRect = shootImage.get_rect()


drawText('Star Trek', font, screen, (WINDOWWIDTH / 2.5), (WINDOWHEIGHT / 3))
drawText('Press a key to start.', font, screen, (WINDOWWIDTH / 3.75) - 30, (WINDOWHEIGHT / 3) + 50)
pygame.display.update()
waitForPlayerToPressKey()

def fire(shoot):
    shootRect.topleft = ((playerRect / 2), 101)
    shootRect.move_ip(5, 1)

topScore = 10000
while True:

    SS = []
    score = 10000
    playerRect.topleft = (0, 100)
    moveUp = moveDown = False
    pygame.mixer.music.play(-1, 0.0)

    while True:
        score -= countBy
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                terminate()

            if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == K_UP:
                    moveDown = False
                    moveUp = True
                if event.key == ord(' '):
                    fire
                if event.key == K_DOWN:
                    moveUp = False
                    moveDown = True

            if event.type == KEYUP:
                if event.key == ord(' '):
                    fire
                if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                        terminate()
                if event.key == K_LEFT or event.key == ord('a'):
                    moveLeft = False
                if event.key == K_RIGHT or event.key == ord('d'):
                    moveRight = False
                if event.key == K_UP or event.key == ord('w'):
                    moveUp = False
                if event.key == K_DOWN or event.key == ord('s'):
                    moveDown = False


        if moveUp and playerRect.top > 0:
            playerRect.move_ip(0, -1 * PLAYERMOVERATE)
        if moveDown and playerRect.bottom < WINDOWHEIGHT:
            playerRect.move_ip(0, PLAYERMOVERATE)


    drawText('Score: %s' % (score), font, screen, 10, 0)
    drawText('Top Score: %s' % (topScore), font, screen, 10, 40)

    screen.blit(playerImage, playerRect)
    screen.blit(shootImage, shootRect)
    screen.blit(baddieImage, baddieRect)
    pygame.display.update()


    if playerHasHitShoot(playerRect, baddieRect):
        score = 0 
    break

    if baddieHasHitShoot(baddieRect, shoot):
        if score > topScore:
            score = topscore
        break
    mainClock.tick(FPS)

pygame.mixer.music.stop()
gameOverSound.play()
drawText('GAME OVER', font, screen, (WINDOWWIDTH / 3), (WINDOWHEIGHT / 3))
drawText('Press a key to play again.', font, screen, (WINDOWWIDTH / 3) - 80, (WINDOWHEIGHT / 3) + 50)
pygame.display.update()
waitForPlayerToPressKey()
gameOverSound.stop()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Many times it's easier for us to find the problem if you boil the code down to be [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In some cases that exercise can even help you find the answer on your own!

Comment: @user3622248, are you sure you've pasted correctly ? Python is indent sensitive and that code doesn't *look* right.

Comment: should i go back to all the code because i don't really know what to edit out of my code. i am new to stack

Answer (score 0):

the answer to why my screen won't refresh is i didn't call the **screen.blit** function